# Delphi. Why compile program in release mode on windows 7 64 bit. But textbox not show text?

Tags: delphi, debugging, textbox, release

I use delphi xe7 and test program on windows 7 64bit and compile in debug mode. My program can work. When I change debug mode to release mode. It has problem about textbox not show message.

```
  TConnectionInfo = Record
    NameConnection : String;
    Server : String;
    Database : String;
    UserName : String;
    Password : String;
    Port : String;
    ConvertZero : String;
  End;


procedure TXMLFrm.AssignToTb1(index:Integer);
begin
   tb1_position.Caption := 'SEQ # ' + IntToStr(index+1) + ' / = ' + IntToStr( Length( AConnection));
   tb1_connection.Caption := 'Connection Name : '+  AConnection[index].NameConnection;
   tb1_database.Caption := 'DataBase Name   : '+  AConnection[index].Database;

   tb1ed_Server.Text := AConnection[index].Server;
   tb1ed_User.Text := AConnection[index].UserName;
   tb1ed_Password.Text := AConnection[index].Password;
end;
```

I can make sure my list array have value 100%.

Why and how to fix problem ?

Thank

[image]

Comment: What message is not shown? How is the message set to the Textbox? Give us a [`MCVE`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that replicates the issue please

Comment: Please see my code in question. And I not set white color in font text box.

Comment: Text boxes work fine. Presumably you aren't putting any text in them. Have you done any debugging?

Comment: That code sample does not mean much when you don't say which textbox is not showing the message or where this procedure is being called from and if AConnection is even initialized. As David mentioned, do some debugging with either CodeSite or message box dialogs to see that the information that you are trying to set is actually there when it is being run

Comment: If i run on debug. Everything Ok. Then I change to compiler on release mode. TextBox not show message. I change compiler mode because debug mode has large execute size.

Comment: Build your program in Release mode instead of compiling.

Comment: The obvious difference between debug and release is different exe-path and because of that a different config file (same name, but also same content?). Just copy the config file from debug to release path and rerun

Comment: Yes I see it about difference between debug and release config. In debug mode my application has large size.But I compiler my application in release mode It has bug about string in textbox not show.

Answer (score 1):

Text boxes, that is `TEdit` controls, are known to work well. This is a fundamental control. If they did not work then somebody would have noticed.

If your text boxes are empty it is because you are not putting any text into them. It would seem that `AConnection[index]` contains some empty strings.

Consider this line of code:

```
tb1_database.Caption := 'DataBase Name   : '+  AConnection[index].Database;
```

Your screenshot shows that the label displays `'DataBase Name   : '` and then no more. How could the control display part of `Caption` but not all of it? Without any doubt `AConnection[index].Database` is empty. Well, it could contain non-printing characters like spaces, but you get my meaning.

We cannot work out why that is so. You will need to do some debugging. The place to start is to think why the debug build may differ from the release build. The obvious difference is that the output folder is different. Does your program read config information from its executable directory?

If you cannot work it out from there then try some debugging. Either use trace debugging (`OutputDebugString` or similar) or use the interactive debugger. You'll need to enable debugging in the release config to do the latter. Remember to revert that change when you've finished debugging.

Comment: Please see my picture in my post And I can make sure AConnection[index] variable have value. Please see Tag # 1/2

Comment: How did you make sure? The screenshot indicates that you are wrong in your belief.  If you put text into the edit controls it would show up. Why do you doubt the evidence?

Comment: David Hefferman Please See Tag # 1/2 In Picture. It is show amount of array.

Comment: The evidence could not be any clearer as I explain in the answer. In order for you to make progress you need to set aside the conspiracy theories and entertain the possibility that your record contains empty values.

Comment: "“select” Isn’t Broken - 
It is rare to find a bug in the OS or the compiler, or even a third-party product or library. The bug is most likely in the application." (The Pragmatic Programmer)

Comment: DavidH is right, and it doesn't sound from what you say as if you've correctly identified the problem.  Instead of assigning the variable you think is not empty to a Caption or TEdit's Text, try assigning an expression which surrounds the variable's value by '>' and '<'.

Comment: @MartynA the example in my answer effectively does that

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You're usually right, of course, but I was just wondering if some unusual byte sequence in the data was causing it not to be displayed correctly.

Comment: @SiWaKorn So, what happened? I guess you discovered you had empty strings right?

Comment: My List Array have string value in my variable. I sure because I has debug my application. But I build release mode on delphi. My string not show.

Comment: Your problem is as I described.

Comment: I have test compile my application in win64 mode. My application can show text in textbox on debug mode and release mode. And thank for David Hefferman.

Comment: For the life of me I cannot understand why you don't believe what I wrote

Comment: I found error. I am stupid. If compile on debug mode (win32 mode) it work. Because compiler automatic initial integer variable equal zero.But compile on release mode compiler not initial variable.

Comment: That's not true. Local variables of unmanaged types are not initialized ever. With all respect, my answer above is correct.